# Is there a way to apply custom filters when reading a row group from a parquet file with pyarrow?

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I'm trying to figure out how [Modin](https://github.com/modin-project/modin) could implement the ability to read Parquet files using filters, with the same behavior as `pandas.read_parquet('my_parquet_file.parquet', filters=[('col', '==', 'val')])`.

Modin distributes the reading of Parquet files by assigning each worker process a set of Parquet [row groups](https://parquet.apache.org/docs/concepts/). Row groups allow a process to seek to a specific part of a file, and read only that part. Currently Modin does this by calling [pyarrow's read_row_groups method](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.html#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.read_row_groups). However, this method does not accept a `filters` parameter, and I cannot find another place in the pyarrow public API that allows reading a single row group while providing filters.

The importance of the filters is that they prevent all the rows from being fully loaded into memory. By doing the filtering operation during the read, the operation only requires as much memory as is needed by the rows actually desired, which may be much smaller than the total set of rows.

Based on [some code in ParquetDatasetV2](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/6b1c7234f7e7fd1d0b543a0513deb3f79f1af131/python/pyarrow/parquet/core.py#L2489-L2509)
I've figured how to do this with private, non-documented functions (and using the `dataset` module, which [warns that it is unstable](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/6b1c7234f7e7fd1d0b543a0513deb3f79f1af131/python/pyarrow/dataset.py#L18)):

```py
from pyarrow.parquet import _filters_to_expression
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

parquet_format = ds.ParquetFileFormat()
fragment = parquet_format.make_fragment('my_parquet_file.parquet', row_groups=[1])

return ds.FileSystemDataset(
    [fragment], schema=fragment.physical_schema,
    format=parquet_format,
    filesystem=fragment.filesystem
).to_table(
    columns=columns, filter=_filters_to_expression(filters),
).to_pandas()
```

Is there a better way, i.e. one that uses PyArrow's stable public API? It seems very strange to me that there would be a way to read row groups from a file, and a way to filter a file, but no way to do both at once.